# How to enable Form 1 from Form 2 in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

on my code in c#, when my form2 shows, my form1 disabled.
now, i added a form2_FormClosed event and what i want to happen is when I closes my form2 using formclosed event the form1 enables.

can someone please help me.

Comment: Maybe you should make form2 modal by using the `ShowDialog()`. This will disable any interaction with form1, didn't it?

Comment: You might have a better chance of having your question answered if you post some code along with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you asked for, literally:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Enabled = false;
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.FormClosed += F2_FormClosed;
        f2.Show();
    }

    private void F2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Enabled = true;
    }
```

But, as stated by xtnd8, it's better to simply use `ShowDialog()`:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog(this);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You must be talking about modal forms, because form1 wouldn't disable when form2 opens, if they are non-model.  You will need a third form to control the action between the forms.  When form2 closes, it needs to reopen form1.

Comment: Third form? Why is that?

Comment: The form that the button click event is on needs to control the opening and closing of the two modeless forms.