# C#, Mechanism behind MessageBox.Show

Tags: c#, multithreading, modal-dialog, messagebox, autoresetevent

In Visual Studio C#, the `MessageBox.Show` will halt, but not lock, the current thread until the message window is closed.

One could even put it in the `if statement` and wait for the result.

In order to understand the mechanism behind it, I tried to make one of my own.

Let say there are 2 forms, `MainForm` and `MsgForm`. `MsgForm` is called from `MainForm` when a button is clicked. You could imagine that the `MsgForm` is my version of `MessageBox.Show`.

The key is for `MainForm` to **wait** for the `MsgForm` until a button in `MsgForm` is clicked.

Which is to say, to make it "modal".

I could manage it simply by calling `MsgForm.ShowDialog()` on `MainForm`, because `ShowDialog()` itself is modal.

But then I thought, what if I don't have that built-in mechanism!? How could I achieve the same thing!?

Since `Show()` isn't modal, so I think it's good to use it for test. If I manage to halt the program with `Show()`, then I succeeded in recreating `MessageBox.Show`.

I first tried to call `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()` on `MsgForm`, it locked the whole thing! Same goes on `MainForm`'s end.

But then I realized that the `WaitOne()` and the `MsgForm` must be called on "different threads" in order to not locking each other.

So I put the following code in `MainForm`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Test())
    {
        label1.Text = "Done!";
    }
}

private bool Test()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(doTest);

    t.Start();
    Class1.ARE.WaitOne();    //ARE is a public static AutoResetEvent in Class1 for global usages.
    return true;
}

private void doTest()
{
    MsgForm frm = new MsgForm();

    frm.Show();
}
```

And simply call `Class1.ARE.Set();` in `MsgForm`'s button click event.

Now it not only locked the whole thing, but also make the `MsgForm` disappear after a "flash".

I'm really at the end of my rope here!

Could somebody PLEASE be so kind and tell me where did I do wrong!?

Much appreciated!

Comment: It's a modal dialog. `frm.ShowDialog()` shows `frm` modally. Very roughly speaking (I haven't done win32 programming in over a decade): While there's a modal dialog showing, the parent window's message loop keeps processing paint messages but not keyboard or mouse messages. I'm googling for documentation on the exact details but coming up empty.

Comment: You could always look at the source code, if you wanted - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/MessageBox.cs

Comment: @DetectivePikachu WOW! This is great! Thanks! I'll definitely go check it out!

Comment: `MessageBox.Show()` doesn't really block a thread. It blocks processing of certain events by the main message pump (and spins up its own). It's pretty complicated and you'd be insane to try it yourself. If you want to prevent an end user from using MainForm while MsgForm is visible, you can [use the Enabled property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31616269/2791540).

Comment: Only [the call to  the native `MessageBox`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/MessageBox.cs,484) is relevant, so you can't actually see what it does.  You don't have to implement your own modal loop. You shouldn't depend on intricate behavior from any modal loop other than knowing it will have a message loop and that it temporarily disables the parent window.